# No chat messages shown in [Gmail]/Chat in mutt

Tags: gmail, mutt

In gmail, my chat history is saved under the label "Chats". When I access gmail labels using mutt, and go to the mailbox under [Gmail]/Chats, it is always empty.

Why are my chats not visible to mutt?